# Difference between including a template in cfc and extending it

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

I thought that one should extend `.cfc` components, but I am reading the `cfwheels` framework source where I see something like this:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" displayName="Controller">
    <cfinclude template="../wheels/controller.cfm">
</cfcomponent>
```

What is the difference between extending the component and including a template as is done above?

Also, are there any scoping issues that I should keep in mind?

Comment: That's a design pattern called [Mixin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin): "In object-oriented programming languages, a mixin is a class that contains methods for use by other classes without having to be the parent class of those other classes. [...] Mixins are sometimes described as being "included" rather than "inherited"." As far as scoping, and functions within the included file should still be properly var-scoped, and the included functions have access to the object they are included in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would totally depend on what was in the included/extended file. One reason this may have been this way is because you can't extend a CFC below the current level (can't do extend="**..**/wheels/controller.cfm"), so this is essentially just "proxying" the file directly. To extend the "../wheels/controller.cfm, you would first have to actually proxy the file by creating a new cfc in the local directory (proxy.cfc) and cfincluding the controller.cfm file in there. Then extend proxy.cfc.

Functionally, they are pretty similar. Conceptually, I would say that an included cfm file may have specific functionality that solves an individual issue whereas an extended cfc file should probably be a wholly functioning piece all on it's own that happens to hold a behavior that the extending class needs.

Comment: I guess one other thing is that you can directly include multiple files, but you can't directly extend multiple files.